# Importing csv in sql server on Mac os with docker gives permission error

Tags: sql-server, docker, csv, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to fill in via Bulk insert statement from a local csv file like this:

```
BULK INSERT Simpson_Paradox 
FROM '/Users/amreshpandey/SimpsonParadoxCase/SimpsonParadox.csv'
 with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')
```

But I get the following error:

> [02:25:43]    Started executing query at Line 1 Msg 4860, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 1 Cannot bulk load. The file
>   "/Users/amreshpandey/SimpsonParadoxCase/SimpsonParadox.csv" does not
>   exist or you don't have file access rights.  Total execution time:
>   00:00:00.007

What am I doing wrong? am I specifying the path to file incorrectly? Many thnx.

OS is Mac High Sierra

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. This worked for me:

First, I copied file from my local file system to that of docker container through:

```
docker cp /Users/ainura/Desktop/file.txt sql_container:/
```

(sql_container is the container name in this case).

Then, I run the bulk insert sql query but still had issue with rowterminator. Instead of writing '\n' for row terminator I tried hex value and it worked perfectly, seems like this is happening because of how file was generated:

```
BULK INSERT Table_name from '/file.txt' 
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '0x0a');
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! This needs file to be present in the docker container. I first copied the file in the container and then, ran the query, and, it worked. Thanks @AinurAin